# plot a customBars and a regular line on the same graph in dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I must have lost my google-fu but I can't figure it out.

I create a graph in dygraphs by passing data like :

```
[
    x, [min,avg,max],val1
]
```

and labels :

```
["Date","the_bar_value","Val1"]
```

and `{customBars:true}` in the options.

Nothing shows.

Is there a way to specify the `customBar` option by series ?
If not how is one supposed to do what I want to do ? I would like to avoid the solution which is to pass the same value 3 times for each date to the series I want to show as single line.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chapo/txLgcepo/6/) that shows the issue : on the second graph there, I would like to show the customBars on the first line but also show the second line.

Comment: From a quick look at the source, it seems like this is not possible - setting `customBars` tells the graph how to handle all data series. Sadly I suspect your 3-value solution may be the best you can do.

Comment: yes I ended up doing that. Shame. Would be cool to be able to set all possible options on a per-series basis instead.

Answer (score 0):

The option `customBars:true` can't be set per series, only globally for all series.

You can enable it and set your data either

```
[
    x, [min, avg, max], [val1, val1, val1]
]
```

or

```
[
    x, [min, avg, max], [null, val1, null]
]
```